# How can I call the function clinet.query through the function?

Tags: reactjs, react-apollo, apollo-client

I would like to call the client.query through function however it does not work. For example, when the user click a button, I want to call a function named handleClick to get the query The following is an example to how call client.query by the function

```
class DelayedQuery extends Component {
    state = { dog: null };

    onDogFetched = dog => this.setState(() => ({ dog }));

    handleClick = (client) => {  //<-------I call the function
        async () => {
            const { data } = await client.query({
                query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
                variables: { breed: "bulldog" }
            });
            this.onDogFetched(data.dog);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloConsumer>
                {client => (
                    <div>
                        {this.state.dog && <img src={this.state.dog.displayImage} />}
                        <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(client) } > Click me! </button> // <-------I call handleClick 
                    </div>
                )}
            </ApolloConsumer>
        );
    }
}
```

How can I call the function clinet.query through the function?

Comment: Is nothing happening? Or do you get a specific error?

Comment: yes is nothing happen

Comment: And where does your code get to? Does it get to the handleClick function?

Comment: Yes, it is exactly like the example

Comment: Shouldn't `handleClick = () => {` be `handleClick = client => {`? Otherwise you're not passing `client` to your `handleClick()` function.

Comment: Just make `handleClick` async ... the inner function never gets called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem by make the handleClick async

```
class DelayedQuery extends Component {
    state = { dog: null };

    onDogFetched = dog => this.setState(() => ({ dog }));

    handleClick = async (client) => {
            const { data } = await client.query({
                query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
                variables: { breed: "bulldog" }
            });
            this.onDogFetched(data.dog);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ApolloConsumer>
                {client => (
                    <div>
                        {this.state.dog && <img src={this.state.dog.displayImage} />}
                        <button onClick={()=>this.handleClick(client) } > Click me! </button>
                    </div>
                )}
            </ApolloConsumer>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So you have 2 problems.
1. You don't pass the client into your function, so that will be a problem, after the function be work. Do it like this:

```
 handleClick = client => {...}
```

2. You don't actual call your inner function in handleClick. You just await the generation of the function. To call it eiter append () after it to call it:

```
async () => {
        const { data } = await client.query({
            query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
            variables: { breed: "bulldog" }
        });
        this.onDogFetched(data.dog);
    }();
```

or separate creation and execution:

```
 async () => {
        const fetch = client.query({
            query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
            variables: { breed: "bulldog" }
        });
        const { data } = await fetch();
        this.onDogFetched(data.dog);
    }
```

or just make the click async:

```
handleClick = async client => {
   const { data } = await client.query({
            query: GET_DOG_PHOTO,
            variables: { breed: "bulldog" }
        });
        this.onDogFetched(data.dog);
}
```

Hope this helps. Happy coding.